# How to compile by maven classes exclude Annotation

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I have maven module where defined JPA Entities with EntityListeners, these  entities will used on other GUI project , this entities will be transferred   using RMI or EJB, but I do not want provide to GUI project any information about Annotation of this entities and EventityListeners  and include dependents JPA  to GUI project.

Is it possible to compile first module without Annotation  and add depends clear jar to GUI?
and will it be correct restored Entity after transfer from server(annotated) module on GUI part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations are not stored in the classes when the retention policy is not RUN TIME. Hence if you could use an alternative jar to redefine these annotations, it would be possible.

A more feasible solution would be **setting the target Java version for compilation to the one before run time annotations** (< Java 1.5).

Comment: Thanks, I will try, and I decide define EventityListeners  in orm.xml and will put enities in separate module  and listeners in other module